# Creating an instance of a generic type

Tags: c#, activator

I have created an each helper like described here: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/14/a-better-razor-foreach-loop.aspx/

Now there is a bussiness rule when there is no items, create a dummy item so the loop gets executed once. Below the foreach statement I add the following:

```
if (!items.Any()) {
    var result = template(new IndexedItem<T>(1, ???));
    result.WriteTo(writer);
}

//Fixed by doing:
var result = template(new IndexedItem<T>(1, default(T)));
```

The questions marks I want to create a dummy object of type T, when searching I found Activator.CreateInstance() But im unable to get that working.

The question I have, first is this the best approach to resolve it, to have it executed once create a dummy object like suggesting above here. If so how would I create the dummy object then ?

Comment: What isn't working with Activator.CreateInstance?

Comment: Creating a dummy object using reflection sounds like a bad idea with many surprises waiting to happen. But more importantly, "the loop gets executed once" doesn't sound like a business requirement, but rather someone's idea of a technical quick-fix. What is the actual *business* requirement? Also, when using generics, you usually simply do `new T()` or `default(T)` instead of using reflection explicitly.

Comment: You can add constraints to your generic type argument: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx With constraints you can use `new` instead of using the code smell of reflection e.g. `public class GenericList<T> where T : new() {`

Comment: I was combining all the solutions to one solution. so I add the new T() and the where T : new() {, so there were some complications and errors. Now Im only using the default(T) Which is working as a charm. Thx :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach would be to use the [`new`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx) constraint for `T` here. So, for example, the `class` or `method` here that defines `T` needs to add a constraint like this:

```
where T : new()
```

Please note that you **must** have a parameterless constructor on `T`, *and* it cannot be `abstract`:

> The new constraint specifies that any type argument in a generic class declaration must have a public parameterless constructor. To use the new constraint, the type cannot be abstract.